# Securing a 70 lbs punching bag safely around a toddler?

Tags: safety

I have an Everlast 70 lbs heavy punching bag that I'd like to hang from an [Everlast Heavy Bag Stand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004HFLUK8); it seems pretty secure to me, I'm thinking that if I use the correct [Carabiner](http://www.gearexpress.com/black-diamond-neutrino-carabiner.html?gclid=CjwKEAiAova1BRDS15OXjcug_FMSJACWNAKZ4tnQ1B4jk170kgcqGxI0uz7dwttg22RXoTs2oVqYmBoCYIrw_wcB) and maybe replace the bolt at the top with something else that doesn't have an open end to it, maybe it will work out.

But I'm also not certain about this, so I figured I would ask here.

Those "spikes" look like this:
[image]

And then up top it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd use some "blue" Locktite on the threads of that bolt at the top, so vibration doesn't eventually unscrew the bolt. (I can't really tell if it has it's own locking mechanism).

Also, use a carabiner that has a screw lock.

Comment: Looking at the photo, the nut already has a "locktight" insert (the blue plastic ring you can see) which does this job.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that picture it's the two weight spikes sticking up from the feet of the stand that would worry me more than the odds of the bag falling... and you can always add a safety strap from the top of the bag to the eye (or tied around the stand in front of the eye)  as a back-up.

Comment: I have a gate too that goes around it, he can move the gate but I doubt he'll be able to reach the bag

Comment: What do you mean by a safety strap?

Comment: But can he move it enough to fall forwards and impale himself onto one of those weight spikes? The safety strap would be more for your main attachment failing while you were working out if he was in the vicinity. By strap, I'm thinking just a cable-lock. Run it through the straps on the top of the bag and through the eye, If the carabiner (or chain) pop loose, if should keep the bag from falling.

Comment: I added an image of the "weight spikes"

Comment: nice job on those :)

Comment: No I didn't do anything that's how they look out of the box.

Comment: Then nice job to the manufacturer. From the pic you provided of that model on Amazon those spikes looked problematic. Glad to see that they aren't.